# Powershell regular expressing to match over multiple lines and replace a small part of what it finds in multiple documents

Tags: powershell, regex, find-and-replace

I'm using powershell to get lots of different documents, find a pattern in them and replace that pattern with something else. I have this working, however I'm trying to expand one of the regular expressions to go over multiple lines to be more accurate now and I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to find a **DOMAIN\UserName** that's with in a certain element and replace it with **NewDomain** keeping the UserName after it what it originally was. E.g.

> ```
>       <gMSA> <!--gManagedServiceAccount, can only be 15 Characters and needs to end with a '$'(Runs AppPool and Broker Services)-->
>           DomainName\UserName
>       </gMSA>
> ```

in Notepad++ this works:

Find:

```
(\<gMSA>.*?\t)D.*?(\\.*?\</gMSA>)
```

Replace:

```
$1NewDomain$2
```

However that doesn't work in powershell. This is what I'm tying to use to replace the text:

```
#Set Install set path
$ProfilePath = 'D:\Customers\Live'

#Update deployparameters in InstallSet Profiles
$DeployParam = Get-ChildItem $ProfilePath deployparameters.xml -rec
foreach ($file in $DeployParam)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '(<gMSA\>.*\t)D.*?(\\.*?</gMSA>)', '$1NewDomain$2' } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

I've tried a few things like `\s` after the `*` to make it go over multiple lines but I have no Joy.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that string, 'only', like that, or is there other stuff in that file? Hence the ask only for the gMSA tag.

Comment: You can't go over multiple lines because the output of `Get-content` doesn't return a string with multiple lines, it returns one separate string per line in the file, and `-replace` applies your regex separately once to each line. You need `get-content -Raw` to return a single multiline string, then you can put `(?s)` at the beginning of your regex to make `.` match linefeed and carriage return and make `.*` go over newline characters.

Comment: @postanote, No there are lots of other modes in the xml file I am reading from which set other settings, so these xml files I am reading from, I just want to target that one line above that's in these xml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TessellatingHeckler had the answer I needed. This is my working solution, simply adding both `-Raw` and `(?s)`

```
#Set Install set path
$ProfilePath = 'D:\Customers\Live'

#Update deployparameters in InstallSet Profiles
$DeployParam = Get-ChildItem $ProfilePath deployparameters.xml -rec
foreach ($file in $DeployParam)
{
    (Get-Content -Raw $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '(?s)(<gMSA\>.*\t)D.*?(\\.*?</gMSA>)', '$1NewDomain$2' } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hummmm, interesting...

Continuing from my comment.

If you are certain that, the pattern is only in the passed string(s)

```
$MyString = @"
      <gMSA> <!--gManagedServiceAccount, can only be 15 Characters and needs to end with a '$'(Runs AppPool and Broker Services)-->
          DomainName\UserName
      </gMSA> 
      <gMSA> <!--gManagedServiceAccount, can only be 15 Characters and needs to end with a '$'(Runs AppPool and Broker Services)-->
          DomainName\UserName
      </gMSA>
      <gMSA> <!--gManagedServiceAccount, can only be 15 Characters and needs to end with a '$'(Runs AppPool and Broker Services)-->
          DomainName\UserName
      </gMSA>
"@
```

Then why not just ask for that.

```
[regex]::Matches($MyString, '(\w.*\\.*)')
# Results
<#
Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 143
Length   : 20
Value    : DomainName\UserName

...
#>

[regex]::Matches($MyString, '(\w.*\\.*)').Value
# Results
<#
DomainName\UserName
DomainName\UserName
DomainName\UserName
#>
```